# Linear Regression Curve Fitting With Scipy - Not sure what is wrong

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, regression, linear-regression

I've been going through threads trying to learn how to fit a curve using linear regression and scipy.

Here's some code I picked up from another kind user helping someone else out.

My issue lies here: I fit some of my own data for `xData` and `yData`. [I get this wrongly fitted curve on my data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7hAn.png)
But If I flip the `xData` and `yData`, then [I get this better fitted curve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LdUe.png)

How do I fix it so that my curve is fitted properly for my original `xData` and `yData` positions?

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings
import math
# det value in dbm
ytoBeConverted = numpy.array([7.76,5.00,1.70,-1.33,-4.77,-7.75,-10.78,-13.76,-16.70,-19.97,-23.04,-25.88,-28.92,-32.05,-34.67,-37.08,-39.33])
#power meter value
lst = []
for y in ytoBeConverted:
    lst.append(math.pow(10, (y/10)))

############ These X and Y data points don't work, but if I flip them as X and Y, it works##########
yData = numpy.asarray(lst)
xData = numpy.array([0.8475,0.7108,0.3853,0.2108,0.1026,0.0537,0.0277,0.0147,0.0079,0.0043,0.0027,0.0019,0.0015,0.0013,0.0012,0.0011,0.0011])


def func(x, a, b, Offset): # Sigmoid A With Offset from zunzun.com
    return  1.0 / (1.0 + numpy.exp(-a * (x-b))) + Offset


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # seach bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # seach bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY]) # seach bounds for Offset

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# generate initial parameter values
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)

print('Parameters', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 
absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('Power Meter Value (mW)') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Detector Value') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: What is your dependent variable and what is the independent one? What do you want to predict?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I want to predict y values from my provided x values. To be more specific, I'm trying to find a relationship between telescope data, Detector Values(X) and Power Meter Value(Y). Detector value decreases with Power Meter Value and I want to be able to interpolate and predict values inbetween my sample data points. To be even more specific, can I just use my properly fitted curve in my example to predict X from Y?

Comment: The confusion is first the values `[7.76, 5.00 ...]` are named as x, then you perform some operation on them and call them y. Then again provide `[0.845, 071...]` as x. Secondly, in the second image also, by inverting the x and y, the y-axis label is "Detector values" for `[0.845, 071...]`. So is the `[0.845, 071...]` values x or y?

Comment: ```[0.845, 071...]``` are the x values. The "wrongly fitted" curve in my picture is the curve I wish to fix.

Comment: @VivekKumar please see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data does not appear to have a sigmoidal shape, so the equation in your code is not fitting the data well. I performed an equation search on your data, and a three-parameter hyperbolic type equation yields an OK fit. Here is your code using this equation with updated genetic algorithm search ranges for the new equation.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings
import math
# det value in dbm
xtoBeConverted = numpy.array([7.76,5.00,1.70,-1.33,-4.77,-7.75,-10.78,-13.76,-16.70,-19.97,-23.04,-25.88,-28.92,-32.05,-34.67,-37.08,-39.33])
#power meter value
lst = []
for x in xtoBeConverted:
    lst.append(math.pow(10, (x/10)))

############ These X and Y data points don't work, but if I flip them as X and Y, it works##########
yData = numpy.asarray(lst)
xData = numpy.array([0.8475,0.7108,0.3853,0.2108,0.1026,0.0537,0.0277,0.0147,0.0079,0.0043,0.0027,0.0019,0.0015,0.0013,0.0012,0.0011,0.0011])


def func(x, a, b, c): # Hyperbolic F from zunzun.com
    return  a * x / (b + x) + c * x


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 0.0]) # seach bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 0.0]) # seach bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # seach bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x


# generate initial parameter values
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)

print('Parameters', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 
absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('Power Meter Value (mW)') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Detector Value') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```